# Complex Xml namespaces in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to create an xml with multiple namespaces in c#.
I am using LINQ XDocument object to create xml. 
The multiple namespaces of xml are causing a lot of confusion.
Can anyone help me out on right direction please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream
xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:6.2" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:n1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095CTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd">
<Form1094CUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
    <SubmissionId>1</SubmissionId>
    <irs:TaxYr>1000</irs:TaxYr>
    <irs:CorrectedInd>true</irs:CorrectedInd>
 </Form1094CUpstreamDetail>
</n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream>
```

C# Code

```
            new XDocument(
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "version", "1.0"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "encoding", "UTF-8"),
                new XElement("n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream","")
            ).Save("sample.xml");
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what problem you are having. Could you re-word with a direct question? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok, in simple words I want to create an xml from c# which is same as above.

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet? Can you provide a sample of the C# you have and where you are stuck? If you have not tried anything, and are looking for a starting place, look into `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`.

Comment: Yes I have tried below code : (please note I have removed extra info to make it clear)  

 `new XDocument(
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "version", "1.0"),
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "encoding", "UTF-8"),
                    new XElement("n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream","")
                ).Save("sample.xml");`'   
 `
It is giving an error for colon ":" after "n1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may be aware, a 'qualified name' in XML is made up of the namespace and the local name.  To make this easier to deal with, you include namespace declarations that prefix these namespaces.

So, for example, where you see `irs:TaxYr`, the qualified name is actually made up of the `urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common` namespace and the `TaxYr` local name.

The prefix values themselves are pretty unimportant - they're just a lookup mechanism.  LINQ to XML will handle this for you automatically (by generating unique prefixes, usually `p1`, `p2` etc.), but you can include them as attributes yourself.  To create such a declaration for the `irs` namespace you'd create the following attribute:

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "irs", "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common")
```

LINQ to XML also provides some nifty implicit conversions, allowing you to create an `XNamespace` and qualified `XName` implicitly from a string.  So, to get your `TaxYr` name you'd do the following:

```
XNamespace irs = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common";
XName taxYr = irs + "TaxYr";
```

Following this all the way through for each of your elements and attributes, your XML could be created declaratively like so:

```
XNamespace def = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:6.2";
XNamespace irs = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common";
XNamespace n1 = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var schemaHint = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095CTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd";

var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(n1 + "Form109495CTransmittalUpstream",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", def),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "irs", irs),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "n1", n1),
        new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaHint),
        new XElement(def + "Form1094CUpstreamDetail",
            new XAttribute("recordType", "String"),
            new XAttribute("lineNum", 0),
            new XElement(def + "SubmissionId", 1),
            new XElement(irs + "TaxYr", 1000),
            new XElement(irs + "CorrectedInd", true)
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was really quick. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally do it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
              "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream" +
                    " xmlns=\"urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:6.2\" xmlns:irs=\"urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common\"" +
                    " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                    " xmlns:n1=\"urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage\"" +
                    " xsi:schemaLocation=\"urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095CTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd\">" +
                "</n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement form109495CTransmittalUpstream = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace  def = form109495CTransmittalUpstream.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace irs = form109495CTransmittalUpstream.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("irs");
            XNamespace n1 = form109495CTransmittalUpstream.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("n1");

            XElement form1094CUpstreamDetail = new XElement(def + "Form1094CUpstreamDetail", new XAttribute[] {
                new XAttribute("recordType", "String"), new XAttribute("lineNum", 0)
            });
            form109495CTransmittalUpstream.Add(form1094CUpstreamDetail);

            form109495CTransmittalUpstream.Add(new XElement("SubmissionId", 1));
            form109495CTransmittalUpstream.Add(new XElement(irs + "TaxYr", 1000));
            form109495CTransmittalUpstream.Add(new XElement(irs + "CorrectedInd", true));

        }
    }
}
​
```